# Number of downloads and updates

Tags: iphone, itunes, statistics

I check my app downloads on AppAnnie. 
Today I've seen that the number of updates is greater than the number of downloads ... how can it be possible ?

Let's say the first version of an app is downloaded 100 times.
If a new version is released and only 50 user updates to the new version than the two numbers become: 100 downloads and 50 updates.
Now, if 100 new user download the app (they can only download the new version) the numbers become: 200 download and 150 updates.

I cannot understand how the number of updates can become greater than number of downloads (probably I've not clear which is the exact meaning of the two numbers).

Comment: Sorry, this is a software development topic and really should be asked on [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com).

Comment: @daviesgeek [iTunes Connect is on-topic](http://meta.apple.stackexchange.com/questions/1664/update-to-faq-about-itunes-connect-being-on-topic)

Comment: @grgarside Okay, sorry. I hadn't seen that meta post and it kinda used to be off-topic...